# Java error in Android Studio but not Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is a Java-newbie question I guess. The following code

```
myClass.addEventListener( MY_EVENT, new EventHandler() {
    @Override public void onEvent( String type, Object payload ) {
        onEventHappens( (int) payload );
    } 
});

private void onEventHappens( int value ) {
    // do something
}
```

works perfectly fine in Eclipse (no warning or error in IDE, execution is fine), but Android Studio says

```
(int) payload
```

is an error; "Inconvertable types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Object' to 'int'

Who is right? I know there's probably a response about "bad coding practice", but my real question is how/why do two development environments treat Java differently?

Comment: int is a primitive type. Object is a reference type. you can convert a primitive type to a reference that by making autoboxing

Comment: is it Lint error or Compile Error?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually far more inclined to believe Android Studio is in the right. Object could be a String, for example, which is not always a number. So the compiler likely refuses to take the risk. It's logic. Intelliji IDEA gave me your error: http://i.gyazo.com/158c471d9eb5ab790cd44a0fc310b831.png

```
myClass.addEventListener( MY_EVENT, new EventHandler() {
    @Override public void onEvent( String type, Object payload ) {
        try {
            onEventHappens( Integer.parseInt(payload) );
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + nfe)
        }
    } 
});

private void onEventHappens( int value ) {

}
```

Come to think of it, I'm actually quite surprised to see that Eclipse wasn't giving you the error, because it really should. You may have disabled it by accident.

Comment: Can you disable errors in addition to warnings? I'm not an expert on compiler design or philosophy, but since it can be done (Eclipse project executes fine), I'm assuming that Android Studio is simply (and firmly) not allowing me to do it (error), instead of just recommending that I don't (warning).

Comment: @user1930720: It **should** be warning you. It's doing its job. Just parse the Int and it will leave you alone.